# Mail on Mac OS X Mavericks automatically unflags all messages

Tags: macos, email

I recently noticed that Mail on my Mac would automatically remove flags from my messages.

I had set up a rule to flag every incoming message so that I do not forget to reply to a message even if it is marked as read.

However, recently Mail started removing the flag from a message if I view it for a few seconds. I also once saw that all flags were gone without me having viewed the messages at all.

Is this a known problem? Any ideas how to prevent Mail from  unflagging messages automatically?

Comment: When I was on Mavericks I wasn't seeing this behavior. What kind of account are you checking (IMAP, POP, Gmail, Exchange?) Can you think of anything you changed before this started happening? Which version of Mavericks are you running?

Comment: I'd be tempted to switch off all rules first, to eliminate those as a possibility.

Comment: I'm using 10.9.5 with an IMAP account (Google Apps). I didn't touch the setup in months, I only recently noticed this behavior.